# .NET tool to generate wrapper for proxy classes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, oop, soap

Using SvcUtil I generated proxy for a SOAP WebService. This webservice has many complex types and can change every year. Is there a tool I can use to generate wrapper for all classes. Using composition in wrapper class I will call proxy class.

Comment: You can try T4Template. Write your custom TT which you can run on you generated proxy classes to create wrapper classes. But AFAIK there's no such utility exist because creating wrapper over proxy is a customized requirement.

Comment: So how do devs handle changes to proxy? Which might cause changes to be done in lot of places of an application.

Comment: To avoid some extent of change impact I personally prefer to use dynamic proxy invocation. Means you don't really need to generate the proxy using svcutil. All the contracts are shared between client and server. So application would just need the Endpoint information rest channel factory would do the needful for invocation. This part you have to do by yourself.

Comment: I will go with T4. I am not sure how flexible channel factory is as I don't have control over Server. Other way would be I guess to generate SOAP XML dynamically which I don't want to do.

Comment: I'm working on creating a demo sample for you.. will put it on `github` in a while. You can take a look and analyze the code. If you have any doubts you can ask me any time :) I'll also add details on how proxy will be decoupled from the service contracts in the answer.

Comment: Here's the github demo of what I was talking about.. I'll write the answer later on.. gotta go now https://github.com/vendettamit/WCFDynamicProxy Cheers!! Checkout Tests project for usage.

Answer (score 0):

Svcutil.exe generate POCO types at the client sides according to the XSD parts of WSDL. There shouldn't be T4Template involved which is too complex and overkill and inappropriate. Svcutil.exe could have created all the proxy classes you need.

If the complex types may be changing every years, you may consider versioning.

Once an interface is published, you should not changed it. This applies to both operation contracts and data contracts.

You may refer to this article [WCF for the Real World](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World), and google WCF versioning.

So basically you explicitly declare XML target namespace in the contracts, and map CLR namespaces with XML namespaces. When you need to change the complex types, you have to provide another version of WCF service. During the transition period before all the clients could upgrade to the latest version, you keep both versions running.

Comment: As mentioned earlier I have no control over Service. I am the client and want to make sure I don't have to make too many changes to my application when Service or complex types changes every year.

Comment: Unless the service provider refuses to publish a WSDL file either through a url or downloadable file, you will use svcutil.exe against the wsdl file to generate proxy classes. Certainly you don't have control over the service, nor you should care about if the service is implemented in .NET, Java or PHP. Evertime the service has some broken changes (hopefully through versioning), you just need to run svcutil.exe against the newly published WSDL again.