# Use auto-generated classes/objects when using a SOAP WS in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, auto-generate

At a current project I have to develop a .NET client application which uses a handful of SOAP web services to communicate with an external software.

Fortunately .NET makes it very easy to use a SOAP WS as it generates all the required objects when adding a service reference.

On the other hand after playing around with this auto generated classes for a while I'm not sure if it's better to use them directly in the business logic or if I should **map them into my own models** (e.g. using something like a repository pattern).

**Pros for mapping:**
 - Separation of business logic and data access  (WS could change)
 - Central point which calls the WS (can validate the responses and do a proper error handling)
 - Sometimes WS types are cumbersome to use (e.g. WebService1.TypeA is not compatible to WebService2.TypeA).
 - Generated classes cannot/should not be customized.
 - ...

**Cons for mapping:**
Some of the used WSDLs have a complex structure and lots of nested types. In case of mapping them to my own models I have to duplicate many classes and properties. That's the fact why I have concerns about this solution.

**In short** I'm unsure if the duplication of the web service classes to my own namespaces and an implementation of a repository or facade pattern is a proper way to go or just blowing up the architecture.

Are there any best practices or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my 20+ years of experience, adding a repository/service layer can be overkill if the lifetime of the project is uncertain or likely to be short lived. There is the added concern of performance, however SOAP itself would be more of a bottleneck than an object mapping layer when done correctly. Also, Naked Object applications don’t benefit from separation of concerns.

That being said, if you are connecting to a SOAP endpoint these days you are likely to be developing an enterprise application that should be built to be around for a few years and enhanced over time. That is, built to accept growing needs. So as far as your pros and cons, in my experience it depends on return on the time investment. From the information you posted here, the extra effort would be beneficial.

Generation can be a great tool when done right. I do a considerable amount of T4 generation in my projects for similar purposes. As far as best practices, I generate my classes into a ‘Generated’ sub namespace and extend them. This way I can extend the functionality and structure without fear of them being overwritten. In the generated classes I mark everything partial and virtual so that I have options outside of inheritance. This may be overkill to do all at once, but is something to consider. Leveraging partial classes could be another way to modify and extend the generated classes.
You can even generate the extended/partial classes.  I use T4Toolbox to generate external files and use the ‘PreserveExistingFile’ to prevent the file from being overwritten. T4Toolbox (if you aren’t already using it) offers a great modular way to manage your generation, even generate into other projects.

Even if you don’t add a repository layer, I would encourage you to apply the concepts of the Composite and Façade patterns to simplify the interaction with the external service.

So in review, best practices in my experience:

**Repository:**

- if you need it to be long-lived and extendable

**Generation:**

- Use a *namespace* and class naming that makes it clear that the class is generated and will be overwritten.
- Create classes that are *partials or extend the generated classes* for flexibility

**T4Toolbox** if using T4

- modular T4
- preserve custom code

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at T4 toolbox. I don't think I will use it in the current project but it seems to be a useful tool.

I recently came across this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400943/net-tool-to-generate-wrapper-for-proxy-classes which is also about using proxy classes or wrappers. This guy wants to wrap all the web service types into custom classes. With your experience, which way would you go? Or is it too specific for a general answer?

Comment: In the case that is presented there, generating some sort of POCO that has no direct relationship would be the best way of dealing with an unstable (read always changing) SOAP service. Another method would be to create a decorator that has knowledge of the web service type but no inheritance/relation (thus not a proxy).  If you are passing web service types on beyond your client, the cleanest way would be a combination of decorator and poco. This way the secondary client/consumer would not need to have any knowledge of the web service types.  But, still it is best to weigh effort to gain.